# What reason can cause the IME language bar invisible in the task bar?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, ime, taskbar

I have a weird issue that the IME is invisible in the task bar when the focus is in a window.
In original code, this window is not permitted to associate with IME and we call "ImmAssociateContext(m_hWnd, NULL)" in the WM_CREATE handler.
Now there is new requirement that we need to permit the user use IME for this window. Then I remove the code "ImmAssociateContext(m_hWnd, NULL)".
To my surprise, the IME is invisble in the task bar even I use the hot key to activate the IME, please refer the screenshot:
[image]

From the above screenshot, the IME is activated actually and the language bar is shown. But it is invisible in the task bar. The normal result should be:

[image]

I investigated this issue for a whole day, but found nothing. Now I have no idea what can cause this issue? Set some window property or else? Anybody can pls give some clues?

Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason that windows has a com ITfLangBarMgr that can hide/show the language bar.